# Import jinja macros in template from outer folder

Tags: python, import, macros, jinja2

I am working on some jinja templates and I need to define some macros that are going to be used within a few template files, but I run into a problem when i try to import it into a template.
I use `jinja2` from `python`.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
templates
|
+--subfolder
|  |
|  + template1.jinja2
|  + template2.jinja2
|
+--subfolder2
|  |
|  + template3.jinja2
|
+ macros.jinja2
```

And in `template1.jinja2` I have the following code:

`{% import "../macros.jinja2" as macros %}`

But i get the following error: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: ../macros.jinja2`

If I move the `macros.jinja2` file to the same folder as the `template1.jinja2` file, and of course remove `../` from the import, it works fine. Same if i create a folder within a `subfolder` such as `macros` and write: `macros/macros.jinja2`.

But unfortunately I am not able to restructure the project due to company policy...

Has anyone got any idea how to import macros from an outer folder?
I have checked the website of jinja and did not find any info on such matter...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Best regards,
Agos

Answer (score 0):

if i am right you want to add all macro file to a macros folder or something related. like so

```
templates
|
+--subfolder
|  |
|  + template1.jinja2
|  + template2.jinja2
|
+--subfolder2
|  |
|  + template3.jinja2
|
+--- macrosfolder
   |
   + macros.jinja2
```

jinja only knows the path to your templates, if your file is nested inside a subfolder in the templates folder you need to specify it to jinja this way

```
{% import 'macrosfolder/macros.jinja2' as foo%}
```

**NOTE**: coming from flask perspective